# How do filter flatlist data according to city from firestore data in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am developing an application for create event and that event should display on home screen according to City. We can choose city through dropdown. I am using Firebase for this application, how can we filter event list according to city??

Comment: Do you want to make a new firebase call when the city is changed or just filter the existing data by the city?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i created collection in firestore then i am fetching that collection data in a list. In the application i have search field where user will search city ...now i am trying to fetch list by city but not able to do

Answer (score 0):

use `useState` to select `city` from drop down and pass to it `FlatList`

```
 <FlatList
   data={itemList?.filter(data => data?.city=== city)}
   keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
   renderItem={renderItem}
 />
```